# Is Sharepoint Designer compatible with Office 2016?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, office-2016

I need to make a compatibility test, so I installed Office 2016 on my Windows 7 test pc, and tried to build up my working environment.
It seems that I cannot install Sharepoint Designer 2010. I tried both 32 and 64 bit versions, but after I launch the installers, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's compatible but you should first install `SharePoint Designer 2010`  **before** installing `Office 2016`.

**So in your case,** to can install and work with `SharePoint Designer 2010` beside `Office 2016`, try to do the following:

- Uninstall Office 2016.
- Install SharePoint Designer 2010 (preferred x64).
- Install Office 2016.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Is this documented somewhere on an MS page too, so I can use it as reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can install and work with the SharePoint Designer 2010 parallel to the Office 2016.

I have development server runs on Windows 7 X64 bit which has Office 2016 and SharePoint Designer 2010 X32 bit.